# View Html in ios/ipod Apps

Tags: ios, web, webview, ipod

Hi i want to make a few http request and generate html from within my ipod app. I hear i want a WebView to view the html as if it were a browser. So my question is how do i make the http request? How do i parse json (or xml) and how do i save/load data? I figure i can use webstorage to load/save the data however i am thinking since its an ipod app i have a better way of storing it?

Answer (score 4):

Here's a snippet to load a local html web page contained inside your app bundle:

```
UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"mywebpage" ofType:@"html"];
[webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path]]];
```

Another alternative is to embed a local web server running in a background thread, and use a URL to localhost.

A UIWebview supports HTML5 local storage.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working code snippet. for iPod/iPhone/iPad;
Works with iOS7 and iOS6.. I have not tested in others...

```
UIWebView *_webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
[self.view addSubview:_webView];

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

[_webView loadRequest:request];
```